# python in vim: 'gf' on import line

Tags: python, vim, editor

In vim pressing `gf` opens the file under the cursor. In python,
modules are imported with '`.`' between the file names where the
path name would contain '`/`'. So `suffixesadd` alone does not suffice.
What is the best solution to get the `gf` functionality in Vim
on import lines in python, such as

```
import hwut.auxiliary.file_system as fs
```

I would like to set the cursor on 'auxiliary', type 'gf' and get
the file opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have

```
filetype plugin on
```

in your vimrc. Then the `gf` on python import should work automatically.

#### update for OP's comment

If you enabled `filetype plugin` and the default `python.vim` ftplugin is gonna be loaded. There the dot `.` in `fname` will be replaced by `/`.

```
setlocal include=^\\s*\\(from\\\|import\\)
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')
```

You can check if your python file hasn't set ft correctly, or you didn't enable filetype in vim.

On my Archlinux distribution with vim80, the python.vim is located at:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin
```

You can get your path by checking `$VIMRUNTIME` var in vim.

Comment: It does not, since it is trying to load a file name containing dots where there are actually supposed to be slashes.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer ok, it does here, without loading extra plugins. without this `plugin on`, it won't work.

Comment: Ok, it is important to note, that 'filetype plugin on' must be active *before* activating 'python.vim'. Then everything works smoothly. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work for my setup (Linux Mint 20.3) because the module can't be found in the path.